# Classical analogue of the theorem of equivalence of the S-matrix

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry

In quantum field theory there is a statement called the equivalence theorem of the S-matrix. S-matrix is invariant under reparametrization of the field. Is there in classical mechanics, the analogous statement, where S-matrix is replaced by the scattering map and the reparametrization - by the canonical transformations (symplectomorphisms).

My question can be reformulated more directly without any reference to quantum mechanics (or QFT). Is the classical scattering map invariant under group of symplectomorphisms ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking? Are you asking about taking a $\hbar \to 0$ limit of something?

Comment: @AHusain I didn't think here about any limit. Although this is a possible way of reasoning. All the objects in my question are well defined (see for example [scattering matrix and associated formulas
in hamiltonian mechanics](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.4172) or [Classical scattering Theory](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-7091-8642-8_2) for terminology)

Comment: @user21963: Aren't all the constructions in the first paper that you link to coordinate-independent? This should guarantee that the S-matrix respects symplectomorphisms.

Comment: Also clarify the dimension you are considering for the quantum system. Are you referring to quantum mechanics scattering problem or an interacting quantum field theory S-matrix?

Comment: @AHusain My question can be formulated more directly without any reference to quantum mechanics (or QFT). Is the classical scattering map invariant under group of symplectomorphisms ?

Comment: When you say "under group of ..." do you mean "under the group of all ..."?

Comment: @Ben McKay  Probably yes. But possible details and corrections are welcome